# Bilateral filter error, Assertion failed ((src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3) && src.data != dst.data)

Tags: java, android, opencv

My code is shown in the following:

```
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
    int width = b.getWidth();
    int height =  b.getHeight();
    Mat tmp = new Mat (width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Mat tmp2 = tmp.clone();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(b, tmp);
    Imgproc.bilateralFilter(tmp,tmp2,10,50,10);
```

and give the following error,

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3) && src.data != dst.data) in void cv::bilateralFilter_8u(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, double, double, int), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.cpp, line 3145

May i ask what's wrong with my code, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the output shown as in ImgProc.bilateralFiler(), as the image that I used is still the shown so where to see the output?

Comment: @arqam please see this link : http://answers.opencv.org/question/16993/display-image/

Comment: @arqam in my code, the image was processed by the OpenCV code, and after that, following the link i mentioned to convert the mat processed into bitmap and set the bitmap to the imageview created in the Android application for output

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and after some reading document, i found the solution. Your Mat read from bitmap wasn't have type 8UC1 or 8UC3, so you should convert it to 8UC3

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(originalMat,originalMat,Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

Now you can use bilateralFilter :)